# row-gap css rule not implement in my builded css from sass

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I am working in a .scss file and I want to implement the instruction `row-gap: 20px;` to have a space betweetn the rows in a grid display. My .scss file looks like this:

```
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  row-gap: 20px !important;
 }
```

But the instruction is getting ignored by the browser. I went to my build folder on the inspector and it seems that is commented.

[image]

But, you've seen that in my .scss file is not commented. I don't know why is happening this.

Comment: whats your browser? and which version?maybe didn't support that. see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-row-gap.asp

Comment: I am using Opera and the version is 80.0.4170.63 so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's weird, so try `grid-row-gap` instead of `row-gap` or use sth like this: `gap: 20px 10px;`